# How to add strip tags in drupal 8?

Tags: 8

How to add strip tag in field template i am using ckeditor in my content type because of using it its automatically inserting p tags in Text.

Here is mine field template code

```
         {% for item in items %}
     <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--item') }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I was trying something like this for adding strip tags

```
{% for item in items %}
{% set conBody %}
 {{ item.content }}
 {% endset %}   

{{ conBody|striptags }}

 <div{{ attributes.addClass(classes, 'field--item') }}>{{ conBody  }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

**Only indexed value(conBody[0]) field tags are stripped(p tags removed) but remaining indexed value fields are remaining same not affected.**

How could i use above code in loop.

Comment: I'm confused, why would you provide CKEditor on a field that you want to strip all tags from?

Comment: Its a clients requirement he wants ck editor fields to style its content by using inline css

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this today and figured I would circle back and provide an answer that worked for me.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% set conBody %}
        {{ item.content }}
    {% endset %}
<div class="myClass">{{ conBody|striptags }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```